# Problem with \multinamedelim and \DeclareNameFormat in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, delimiters

I have changed the delimiter for the authors in the bibliography with this code. It is working.

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

But I add also commands to my preamble for changing the order and the authors' names. And now the delimiter as comma do not show up.

```
\DeclareNameFormat{lastname}{#1\addspace}
\DeclareNameFormat{last-init}{#1 #4\addspace}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{lastname}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{lastname}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-init}

\DeclareSortingScheme{last}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
 \sort[final]{
    \field{author}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{title}
    \field{year}
  }
}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
      \map{
        \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{(.+)\sand}, final]
        \step[fieldset=sortname, fieldvalue=$1, final]  }
}}
```

Comment: Your definitions of `lastname` and `last-init` seem somewhat fishy, try `\DeclareNameFormat{lastname}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-init}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}` (modulo linebreak) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your definitions of `lastname` and `last-init` seem somewhat fishy, try the definitions

```
\DeclareNameFormat{lastname}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-init}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I try this as a minimal example I already get an `Package keyval error: fieldname undefined`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameFormat{lastname}{#1\addspace}
\DeclareNameFormat{last-init}{#1 #4\addspace}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{lastname}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{lastname}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-init}

\DeclareSortingScheme{last}{
    \sort{
        \field{presort}
    }
    \sort[final]{
        \field{author}
    }
    \sort{
        \field{title}
        \field{year}
    }
}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=author, match=\regexp{(.+)\sand}, final]
            \step[fieldname=sortname, fieldvalue=$1, final]
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, if I interpret your code correctly, you might just want??

```
\usepackage[sorting=nty,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\multilistdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```